# jQuery .search() to any string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I saw this code snippet:

```
$("ul li").text().search(new RegExp("sometext", "i"));
```

and wanted to know if this can be extended to any string?

I want to accomplish the following, but it dosen't work:

```
$("li").attr("title").search(new RegExp("sometext", "i"));
```

Also, anyone have a link to the jQuery documentation for this function? I fail at googling apparently.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`search()` is a String method.

You are executing the `attr` function on **every** `<li>` element.
You need to invoke `each` and use the `this` reference within.

Example:

```
$('li').each(function() {
    var isFound = $(this).attr('title').search(/string/i);
    //do something based on isFound...
});
```

Comment: I think $(this).attr('title') is already a string. Do we still need to convert it to string again ?

Answer (score 8):

```
if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf("yes") >= 0)
```

Or,

```
if (/yes/i.test(str))
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah, that would be because RegExp is not jQuery. :)

Try [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp). `jQuery.attr` doesn't return a String so that would certainly cause in this regard. Fortunately I believe you can just use `.text()` to return the String representation.

Something like:

```
$("li").val("title").search(/sometext/i));
```