# Reading Dynamic JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, eval, arrays

I trying to build a JavaScript function which will grab a JSON encoded array and return a value based on the requested key. I use the jQuery $.parseJSON() method to take the JSON string and convert it into a JavaScript object. Here a watered down example:

```
function getValue(dynamicArrayKey) {
  var theArray = $.parseJSON(/* Get some JSON from a source using jQuery */);

  alert('Here is the value: ' + theArray.dynamicArrayKey);
}
```

So the key I want will be given to the function, and it should return the resulting value. I am thinking that the JavaScript `eval()` method should be used in there somewhere, but I'm not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to eval(), use

```
alert('Here is the value: ' + theArray[dynamicArrayKey]);
```

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm!

I was wondering, though, why can I do something like this: "theArray.notDynamicArrayKay", when I'm actually looking for a key by that name, but I have to use the "theArray[dynamicArrayKey]" when the value I'm looking for a value that is dynamic? Just curious.

Comment: It's called subscript notation. You may take a look at http://www.crockford.com/misty/objects.html :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. It may help.

[How to search JSON tree with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288833/how-to-search-json-tree-with-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but I'm afraid that would involve too much redundant processing for a simple task, especially since this function will be called rather frequently.