# How to find a string in all key value pair of json In Javascript for creating an searching pipe in Angular 2

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and I'd like to filter out objects based on matching values.

```
var a = [
    {name:'xyz' , grade :'x'},
    {name:'yaya' , grade :'x'},
    {name:'x' , frade:'d'},
    {name:'a',grade:'b'}
]
```

If I want to filter on `'x'` then I'd expect the following results:

```
[
    {name:'xyz' , grade :'x'},
    {name:'yaya' , grade :'x'},
    {name:'x' , frade:'d'},
]
```

I have tried this

```
   a.filter(function(d) {
        return d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKey.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
            d.grade.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKey.toLowerCase()) > -1
    });
```

but I don't want hardcoded keys.

Comment: So loop over the keys.

Comment: Is the array always going to be one dimensional?

Comment: @Jerry yes with different keys

Comment: Man, all the answers on that dupe are outdated.

Comment: Post an answer in the dupe with Object.keys, filter, includes, some http://stackoverflow.com/a/40890687/14104

Comment: you might consider a search with a key or over all keys. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40890778/1447675

Comment: all keys @NinaScholz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function yourSearch (array, search) {

    return array.filter((el) => {
      for (let param in el) {
        if (el.hasOwnProperty(param) && Array.isArray(el[param])) {
          if (el[param].indexOf(search) !== -1) return true;
        }
      }
    });

}
```

enjoy

if without es6 replace `(el) =>` with `function (el)`

edit: added reply to comment

Comment: getting error el[param].indexOf is not a function

Comment: fixed, one of your keys is not an array, added check