# TypeError: obj[key].includes is not a function when filtering values of an object in an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, filtering

I wanted to filter the values in an array of objects by a certain value. When I run the function, I get `TypeError: obj[key].includes is not a function`. I am using reactjs. What I'm I missing in the function?

```
var arr = [{
 name: 'xyz',
 grade: 'x'
}, {
 name: 'yaya',
 grade: 'x'
}, {
 name: 'x',
 frade: 'd'
}, {
  name: 'a',
  grade: 'b'
}];

filterIt(arr, searchKey) {
  return arr.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj)
    .map(key => obj[key].includes(searchKey)));
}
```

I got this example from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40890687/5256509 and tried it out

Comment: so what is `obj[key]` ? Sounds like it is not what you think it is.

Comment: What's `obj`? Are all of the properties of it objects with an `includes` method?

Comment: `obj[key]` is the value of the `key` passed @epascarello

Comment: What is it when it fails.... Not seeing an the array/objects your question is basically impossible to answer.

Comment: @epascarello I have updated the question

Comment: Obviously `obj[key]` doesn't contain something that has an `includes` function. Not much to see here.

Comment: And what browser are you using?

Comment: Maybe you are using browser that doesn't support  String.prototype.includes. Like IE, for example.

Comment: Chrome Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)

Comment: The symptoms seem to suggest your example doesn't have the array you're using.

Comment: I actually pasted this on repl.it and although I am not getting an error, I am getting all the objects in the array

Comment: Of course you are getting all the object in the array. Object.keys.map is always truthy.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I get it now @dfsq

Comment: Check the answer I just posted, maybe you can do it like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't filter array of object like this, because this combination

```
Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key].includes(searchKey))
```

always provides an array (with `true` and `false` values), and any array is truthy. Hence filter doesn't filter anything. You can try something like this:

```javascript
arr.filter(obj => 
   Object.keys(obj)
     .some(key => obj[key].includes(searchKey))
);
```

Comment: Thanks for edit! Of course, `Array.prototype.some` is much better here.

Comment: Yeah researched about `map` and other array methods and discovered my mistake. Thanks for helping