# search and replace object to update

Tags: javascript

Im trying to find a "item" object which has updated values, based on another "item" object (visItem) in this case.

then I want to overwrite the "visItem" with the found and updated "item"

I have tried to base it on something like the link below, but im not sure how to implement it in my scenario. Searching and then overwriting the outdated object.

[JS search in object values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517089/js-search-in-object-values)

Here is some pictures to set the scene.

**not updated object**
[image]

**update section containing the wanted item**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to iterate through the items array, and find an object where the grpid and id match?

if so, you could do a simple search:

```
for(i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    if(items[i].grpid === visItem.grpid && items[i].id === visItem.id) {
        //Match found
        visItem = items[i]; //Overwrites visItem with the found item
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the [FindIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) , with using this you can find index in the array of the object and replace it with your data.

```
var item = {YOUR UPDATED ITEM}
var items = [YOUR ARRAY OF ITEMS];

var getIndex= items.findIndex(x => x.id == item.id);
items[getIndex] = item;
```

Comment: There is just one problem. The updated object is in the list of many items. The one that needs updateing is the singular item ( visItem) object.

Comment: The other way around is also possible, you just need to change the last line like YOUR_OBJECT_NAME.visItem = items[getIndex]