# How to find specific date from js array?

Tags: javascript

I have this array in my data.js file. And I want to find the specific date from other html file to data.js file using javascript.

For example:

> Here is the date to search
>
> var searchDate = '12-25-2017';
>
> I want to search that date from ***data.js*** file ( **Variable name : *jpHolidays*** )and show in html or console.log().

I was googling and i didn't find how to find the specific date. Please help me.

```
var jpHolidays = {
     '01-01-2017' : '<span>お正月 <br> New Year\'s Day</span>',
     '01-02-2017' : '<span>お正月 <br> New Year\'s Day observed</span>',
     '01-09-2017' : '<span>成人の日 <br> Coming of Age Day</span>',
     '02-11-2017' : '<span>建国記念日 <br> National Foundation Day</span>',
     '03-20-2017' : '<span>春分の日 <br> Vernal Equinox Day</span>',
     '04-29-2017' : '<span>昭和の日 <br> Shōwa Day</span>',
     '05-03-2017' : '<span>憲法記念日 <br> Constitution Memorial Day</span>',
     '05-04-2017' : '<span>みどりの日 <br> Greenery Day</span>',
     '05-05-2017' : '<span>こどもの日 <br> Children\'s Day</span>',
     '07-17-2017' : '<span>海の日 <br> Marine Day / Ocean Day</span>',
     '08-11-2017' : '<span>山の日 <br> Mountain Day</span>',
     '09-18-2017' : '<span>敬老の日 <br> Respect for the Aged Day</span>',
     '09-23-2017' : '<span>秋分の日 <br> Autumnal Equinox Day</span>',
     '10-09-2017' : '<span>体育の日 <br> Health and Sports Day </span>',
     '11-03-2017' : '<span>文化の日 <br> Culture Day</span>',
     '11-23-2017' : '<span>勤労感謝の日 <br> Labour Thanksgiving Day </span>',
     '12-23-2017' : '<span>天皇誕生日 <br> The Emperor\'s Birthday</span>',
 };
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: '12-25-2017' is not in your holidays object

Comment: Just FYI guys, `jpHolidays` is not an array. Its an object.

Comment: This is actually object, and you need to get coresponding key and value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517089/js-search-in-object-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `jpHolidays` is an object and not an array.

```
var jpHolidays = {
     '01-01-2017' : '<span>お正月 <br> New Year\'s Day</span>',
     '01-02-2017' : '<span>お正月 <br> New Year\'s Day observed</span>',
     '01-09-2017' : '<span>成人の日 <br> Coming of Age Day</span>',
     '02-11-2017' : '<span>建国記念日 <br> National Foundation Day</span>',
.....
....
}


//assume that this is the holiday you are looking for
var isHoliday = '12-25-2017';

// access the jpHolidaysObject. if found, return the value. If not, print 'not holiday' or whatever suits you.

console.log(jpHolidays[isHoliday] || 'not holiday');
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. I got it .

Answer (score 2):

This is not an array. This is a JS object. Here is how you can iterate the properties of an object

```
for (var day in jpHolidays) {

  if (jpHoldays.hasOwnProperty(day) && day === searchDate) {
     console.log(jpHolidays[day]);  
  } 

}
```

It explains as - the `for` iterator takes you through all the properties of `jpHolidays`. You try to compare each property with your search string. The `hasOwnProperty` is to only consider the properties of the object - not the properties which it inherits prototypically.

Also, you can access the `jpHolidays` like `jpHolidays[searchDate]` as a direct approach.

---

This is a JS array `a = [1, 2, 3];`

This is an object `a = {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3};`

JS doesn't have associative arrays.

Comment: You no need to iterate through all the key to get a value right?

Comment: How can i find From Date To Date in that object array? please.

Answer (score 1):

A) Declare it as a global variable.

```
window.jpHolidays = {
     '01-01-2017' : '<span>お正月 <br> New Year\'s Day</span>',
     '01-02-2017' : '<span>お正月 <br> New Year\'s Day observed</span>',
     ...
};
```

B) Load data.js file before the file that you will use.
So the global variable, `jpHolidays`, can be stored in *window*. Like below:

```
<script src="data.js"></script>
<script src="yourFile.js"></script>
```

C) Grab datas from `window.jpHolidays`

```
console.log(jpHolidays['01-01-2017']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hasOwnProperty method to check for a key.

```
var searchDate = '12-25-2017';

if(jpHolidays.hasOwnProperty(searchDate)){
  //write your logic here or return jpHolidays[searchDate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`jpHolidays` is not an Array but an Object. You can access a particular value in that object by providing a key:

```
var result = jpHolidays[searchDate]
```

If you want to check wether a specific key exists at all in the object use the 'in' operator:

```
if (searchDate in jpHolidays) { // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access the object (not array) directly:

```js
var jpHolidays = {
     '01-01-2017' : '<span>お正月 <br> New Year\'s Day</span>',
     '01-02-2017' : '<span>お正月 <br> New Year\'s Day observed</span>',
     '01-09-2017' : '<span>成人の日 <br> Coming of Age Day</span>',
     '02-11-2017' : '<span>建国記念日 <br> National Foundation Day</span>',
     '03-20-2017' : '<span>春分の日 <br> Vernal Equinox Day</span>',
     '04-29-2017' : '<span>昭和の日 <br> Shōwa Day</span>',
     '05-03-2017' : '<span>憲法記念日 <br> Constitution Memorial Day</span>',
     '05-04-2017' : '<span>みどりの日 <br> Greenery Day</span>',
     '05-05-2017' : '<span>こどもの日 <br> Children\'s Day</span>',
     '07-17-2017' : '<span>海の日 <br> Marine Day / Ocean Day</span>',
     '08-11-2017' : '<span>山の日 <br> Mountain Day</span>',
     '09-18-2017' : '<span>敬老の日 <br> Respect for the Aged Day</span>',
     '09-23-2017' : '<span>秋分の日 <br> Autumnal Equinox Day</span>',
     '10-09-2017' : '<span>体育の日 <br> Health and Sports Day </span>',
     '11-03-2017' : '<span>文化の日 <br> Culture Day</span>',
     '11-23-2017' : '<span>勤労感謝の日 <br> Labour Thanksgiving Day </span>',
     '12-23-2017' : '<span>天皇誕生日 <br> The Emperor\'s Birthday</span>',
 };
searchDate = '12-23-2017';
document.write(jpHolidays[searchDate]);
```