# Javascript-searching for a string in the properties of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have an array of JSON objects. Given a search string, I want to filter the array for only those objects which have that string as a substring of one of their properties. How do I do this efficiently?

Comment: provide a [mcve] along with an example of search string and the JSON itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS search in object values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517089/js-search-in-object-values)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming you want to find the substring in the property *value*, you can use the following code:

```js
const arr = [
  {a:'abc', b:'efg', c:'hij'},
  {a:'abc', b:'efg', c:'hij'},
  {a:'123', b:'456', c:'789'},
];

const search = 'a';

const res = arr.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).some(val => val.includes(search)));

console.log(res);
```

If you want to search the property *name*, use `Object.keys` instead of `Object.values`.

Please note that `Object.values` is a feature of ES2017.

Comment: I'm getting val.includes is not a function in chrome console.

Comment: Then either you are using different code or a very old version of Chrome.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error. val.includes is not a function in chome. BTW i'm using latest version of chromeEdit: Figured out the issue. In my case, one of the object values was not a string, where this error comes up.

Comment: dont forget to check the value using typeof === 'string'

Answer (score 11):

Works like a charm:

```js
data.filter((obj) =>
  JSON.stringify(obj).toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
)
```

Comment: This will also check if the keys of the object contains the `query`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to do something like this:

```
var list = [
    {var1: "value1", var2: "value2", var3: "value3"},
    {var1: "value4", var2: "value5", var3: "value6"},
    {var1: "value4", var2: "value3", var3: "value2"},
    {var1: "value2", var2: "value8", var3: "value6"},
    {var1: "value1", var2: "value7", var3: "value7"},
    {var1: "value1", var2: "value6", var3: "value2"},
];

var searchString = "value2";

var newList = list.filter(element => {
    for (var property in element) {
        if (element.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if(element[property] == searchString) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
});

console.log(newList);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `filter` method to filter the array and then use the `Object.keys` function to get an array of keys on the current object.  You can then loop over each key and check if it has the substring (I added some guards to protect against calling `.indexOf` on an identifier without that method.)

```
const search = 'xyz';
const data = yourDataFunction();
const filteredData = data.filter(item => {
  let found = false;
  Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
    if (item[key] && item[key].indexOf && item[key].indexOf(search) > -1) {
      found = true;
    }
  });
  return found;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myStr = 'abc';
var myArr = [{abc:1,def:2}, {ghi:1,jkl:2}];
myArr.filter( obj => Object.keys(obj).some( key => key.indexOf(myStr) > -1 ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out a method that works for me. I went further to convert the query string to lower case:

```js
const data = [
   {a: 'ekom', b: 'obong'},
   {a: 'fin', b: 'barr'}
];

const queryString = 'fi';

const result = data.filter((obj) => JSON.stringify(obj).toLowerCase().includes(queryString.toString().toLowerCase()));

console.log('Result: ', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A little improvement to str's answer, for better performance;

```
const arr = [
  {a:'abc', b:'efg', c:'hij'},
  {a:'abc', b:'efg', c:'hij'},
  {a:'123', b:'456', c:'789'},
];

const search = 'a';

const res = arr.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).some(val => val.indexOf(search) >= 0));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @str to contribute. I just update it a little bit because it's not working a newer version of js is in strict mode. We need to covert the final `val` to string before checking `includes` method.

```
const arr = [
   {a: 'abcd', b: 'cdaf'},
   {a: 'xyz', b: 'axcfd'}
];

const searchValue = 'a';

const newArr = arr.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).some(val => val.toString().includes(searchValue)));
```