# Filter one object with another object recursively

Tags: javascript, object, filter

What i am trying to do is filter one object using another. I have it working for the keys such as name or email but the problem is for the address field where it needs to check the value recursively.

I have the following object:

```
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "name": "Michael",
    "surname": "Smith",
    "emailAddress": "m.smith@gmail.com",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Sam",
    "surname": "Smith",
    "emailAddress": "s.smith@gmail.com",
    "address": {
      "text": "123 Fake Street, Some Place, United kingdom",
      "street_number": "123",
      "route": "Fake Street",
      "locality": "Some Place",
      "country": "UK",
      "postcode": "HP18",
      "lat": 51.648858999292999,
      "lng": 4.08207329992999786,

    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Josh",
    "surname": "Fradley",
    "emailAddress": "myemai@gmail.com",
    "address": {
      "text": "1 Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA, USA",
      "street_number": "1",
      "route": "Apple Park Way",
      "locality": "Cupertino",
      "administrative_area_level_1": "California",
      "country": "US",
      "postcode": "95014",
      "lat": 37.3346326,
      "lng": -122.01268240000002,
    }
  }
]
```

Example search object

```
{
  "name": "",
  "phone": "",
  "address": "",
  "emailAddress": "myemai@gmail.com"
}
```

The code i use for the email and name fields

```
  let res =  array.filter(o => 
    Object.keys(searches).every(k => 
      o[k] && o[k].length ? removeDiacritics(o[k].toLowerCase()).indexOf(removeDiacritics(searches[k].toLowerCase())) >= 0 : true
   ));
```

What i am struggling with is how to search the address key which is an object, for example if i search "address": "Fake Street" it should return id 2

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the filters array is dynamic so i cant hard code in "address", i used here as an example of an object

Comment: I think you don't need recursion for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript-searching for a string in the properties of an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47653927/javascript-searching-for-a-string-in-the-properties-of-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Why can't you do something like `array.filter(o => o.address && o.address.text && o.address.text.includes(searchString))` ?

Comment: is an empty sting a value to search for?

Comment: these filters can be dynamic so the value "address" might change. I used here as an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a local function and check the value of the object for nested objects.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: "Michael", surname: "Smith", emailAddress: "m.smith@gmail.com" }, { id: "2", name: "Sam", surname: "Smith", emailAddress: "s.smith@gmail.com", address: { text: "123 Fake Street, Some Place, United kingdom", street_number: "123", route: "Fake Street", locality: "Some Place", country: "UK", postcode: "HP18", lat: 51.648858999293, lng: 4.082073299929998 } }, { id: 3, name: "Josh", surname: "Fradley", emailAddress: "myemai@gmail.com", address: { text: "1 Apple Park Way, Cupertino, CA, USA", street_number: "1", route: "Apple Park Way", locality: "Cupertino", administrative_area_level_1: "California", country: "US", postcode: "95014", lat: 37.3346326, lng: -122.01268240000001 } }],
    search = { name: "", phone: "", address: 123, emailAddress: "" },
    result = data.filter(o => Object.entries(search).every(([k, v]) => {
        function check(value) {
            return value && typeof value === 'object'
                ? Object.values(value).some(check)
                : value.toString().includes(v);
        }

        if (v === '') return true;
        if (k in o) return check(o[k]);
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this is so close but i want address to search through all the keys in address, not having to specific street_number

Comment: please add a search object and the result.

Comment: {address : 123 }
Would return id 2, for example as 123 is in text and street number 

{ id: "2", name: "Sam", surname: "Smith", emailAddress: "s.smith@gmail.com", address: { text: "123 Fake Street, Some Place, United kingdom", street_number: "123", route: "Fake Street", locality: "Some Place", country: "UK", postcode: "HP18", lat: 51.648858999293, lng: 4.082073299929998 }

Comment: you want to search the address in obj1 key with all the keys in address object obj1 and you don't want to hardcode the key address...
my question is always address may become object or other keys may be an object too

Comment: No addres is only example could be products or any over object

Comment: TypeError: value is undefined when searching for {address : 123 }

Comment: you could treat all values as strings. please see edit.

Comment: that works perfectly i added: 

    if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
              return false;
         }