# How to filter an object?

Tags: javascript

I want to filter an object and made this:

```
filteredList() {
      return this.messages.filter(message => {
        return message.number.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())      
      })
    }
```

But this method works only for number in message. What if I want to search the value in whole object?

Comment: Hi, Can you please post sample input/output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517089/js-search-in-object-values This link might help.Thanks

Comment: Are you using an array ?

Comment: Make a clear example of what you are trying to achieve and where you have failed  to get the desired result

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean searching for a string in all member variables you can just use an or operator to search different fields like `return message.number.contains(x) || message.content.contains(x);`

Also, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735184/5713970) that uses a loop to iterate over properties of a variable. You could return true for each property that contains the search string