# Find index of object by id in array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of houses which has an array of rooms inside.

Each room, house, and street has a unique ID (eg: If rooms in house 1, have ID 1..4, rooms in house 2 will have ID 5..9)

```js
    var street = {
        id = 1,
        streetname = 'stack street',
        houses = [
            {
                id: 1,
                type: 'brick'
                rooms: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        color: 'blue'
                    }, ... a bunch more
                ]
            }, ... a bunch more
        ]
    }
```

Are there easy solutions like `arr.findIndex()` for:

1. Given a room ID, return the index of the house in the array houses, and the index of the room in the array rooms of that house
2. Given a room ID, return the house it's in
3. Given a room ID, return the room object

Comment: Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517089/js-search-in-object-values
or search around other questions for finding an array (of objects) index by searching contained values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The `findIndex()` is that easy solution but you need to employ an array function once more to scan through rooms within the house check callback:

```
var houseIndex = street.houses.findIndex(h => h.rooms.some(r => r.id === roomId));
```

2) Just the same with `find()`:

```
var house = street.houses.find(h => h.rooms.some(r => r.id === roomId));
```

or if the earlier index lookup is in place, use its result:

```
var house = street.houses[houseIndex];
```

3) Flatten the house-room hierarchy into a plain room list and search it for the desired room:

```
var room = street.houses.flatMap(h => h.rooms).find(r => r.id === roomId);
```

Answer (score 0):

For room id 7:

1)

```
int houseIndex = street.houses.findIndex(house => house.rooms.find(room => room.id == 7));
int roomIndex = street.houses.find(house => house.rooms.find(room => room.id == 7)).rooms.findIndex(room => room.id == 7)
```

2)

```
var houseObject = street.houses.find(house => house.rooms.find(room => room.id == 7))
```

3)

```
var roomObject = street.houses.find(house => house.rooms.find(room => room.id == 7)).rooms.find(room => room.id == 7)
```