# Problem in looping a JSON array in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to loop through a JSON Array to search for a keyword. I am refering [this thread to achieve this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517089/js-search-in-object-values)

entries is a JSON array of stucture

```
[
    {"a": "something", "id": 54785, "b": ["each", "every", "one"]},
    {"a": "something", "id": 54785, "b": ["each", "every", "one"]},
    {"a": "something", "id": 54785, "b": ["each", "every", "one"]},
]
```

`searchItem` came from this custom component

```
<FormInput type="text"
    v-model="searchItem"
    @input="searchObject()"
    placeholder="Search here">
</FormInput>
```

I placed my function in methods of component like this.

```
searchObject: function() {
  for (var i=0; i<this.entries.length; i++) {
    for (var key in this.entries[i]) {
      if (this.entries[i].key.indexOf(this.searchItem)!==-1) {
        this.result.push(this.entries[i])
      }
    }
  }
  return this.result
}
```

I get this error in console

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

When I change in computed function and try `[key]` instead of `.key`

```
searchObject() {
  for (var i=0; i<this.entries.length; i++) {
    for (var key in this.entries[i]) {
      if (this.entries[i][key].indexOf(this.searchItem)!==-1) {
        this.result.push(this.entries[i])
      }
    }
  }
  return this.result
}
```

I am not getting anything pushed in result, neither I am getting any error in console. I tried to put console.log() command on my function, but again nothing on console.

Comment: What is `this.result`? Where is it defined?

Comment: in `data(){return{result:[]}}`

Comment: Which keys do you want to search within? Does your structure include nested objects and arrays?

Comment: I have many keys similar to `a`, `id` and `b`. I would like to search for likes of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each object doesn't have any deeply nested objects or arrays inside it, you can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the values of your object.

With your current data, the returned values will contain another array so you have to flatten it by using [`.concat.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to merge the values into one array.

Using the flattened array, you can then easily check if the current object contains your `searchItem`.

**Edit:** If you want to include an item to the result if the `searchItem` matches certain parts of the item values, you can use `.join` to concatenate your flattened values into a string.

See example below:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    result: [],
    searchItem: '',
    entries: [{
        "a": "something",
        "id": 54785,
        "b": ["one", "two", "three"]
      },
      {
        "a": "nothing",
        "id": 54785,
        "b": ["each", "every", "one"]
      },
      {
        "a": "everything",
        "id": 54785,
        "b": ["each", "every", "one"]
      },
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    searchObject: function() {
      this.result = []; // clear data, for demonstration only, remove if not needed

      for (var i = 0; i < this.entries.length; i++) {
        var values = [].concat.apply([], this.getValues(this.entries[i]));
        
        // you can also convert it to a string to match certain string parts
        values = values.join(',');
        
        if (values.indexOf(this.searchItem) !== -1) {
          this.result.push(this.entries[i])
        }
      }
    },
    getValues: function(object) {
      // use a polyfill in case Object.values is not supported by current browser
      return Object.values ? Object.values(object) : Object.keys(object).map(key => object[key]);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="searchItem" v-on:input="searchObject" placeholder="Search here" />
  <ul>
    <li v-for="i in result">{{i}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way I can find `something` when I am searching `some`.

Answer (score 0):

here is simple demo :

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    result:[],
    searchItem:'',
    entries:
     [
{"a": "something", "id": 54785, "b": ["each", "every", "one"]},
{"a": "something", "id": 54785, "b": ["each", "every", "one"]},
{"a": "something", "id": 54785, "b": ["each", "every", "one"]},
]
  },methods:{
    searchObject:function(){
       for (var i=0; i<this.entries.length; i++) {
        for (var key in this.entries[i]) {
            if (key.indexOf(this.searchItem)!==-1) {
            this.result.push(this.entries[i])
            }
        }
      }
      if(this.searchItem && this.searchItem.length>0){
        return this.result;      
      }else{
         return this.result=[];
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input
type="text"
v-model="searchItem"
v-on:input="searchObject"
placeholder="Search here" />
<p>{{'searchItem :'+searchItem}}</p>
<ul>
<li v-for="i in result">{{i}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you are searching in the `key` itself, i want to search it in `value`

Comment: which value you want to search , id or b array ?

Comment: There are many fields like `a` and `b` that I want to search on.