# Displaying specific id from json file with reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

How could I display data from a `json` file using `reactjs`.

I would like to display a specific value on my website using a `json` file.
Using this example `json` file.

```js
const data = [
  {
    items: {
      item: [
        {
          id: "0001",
          type: "donut",
          name: "Cake",
          ppu: 0.55,
          batters: {
            batter: [
              {
                id: "377",
                type: "Regular",
              },
              {
                id: "609",
                type: "Chocolate",
              },
              {
                id: "788",
                type: "Blueberry",
              },
              {
                id: "809",
                type: "Devil's Food",
              },
            ],
          },
          topping: [
            {
              id: "5001",
              type: "None",
            },
            {
              id: "5002",
              type: "Glazed",
            },
            {
              id: "5005",
              type: "Sugar",
            },
            {
              id: "5007",
              type: "Powdered Sugar",
            },
            {
              id: "5006",
              type: "Chocolate with Sprinkles",
            },
            {
              id: "5003",
              type: "Chocolate",
            },
            {
              id: "5004",
              type: "Maple",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
];
```

How could I access for example `items.item.batters.batter` for `id 609` and display the `type` in this case `"Chocolate"` using `reactjs` without using something like this:

```
batters.batter[1].type
```

and instead displaying it for the specific `id` (`609`)?

Comment: Do you want to map through the data and display the list? Or what is the problem with your current solution?

Comment: I just want to display this one item. The problem is that my actual json file keeps changing so using this method will sometimes return another item depending my database content. So i need to specifically look for and display id x. So sometimes my item { id: "609", type: "Chocolate" } will be batter[1] sometimes it is batter[6] or something depending on the content

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find a specific object, that has a specific value in a list of objects, you can do it as such:

```
const [batter, setBatter] = useState([
  {
    id: "377",
    type: "Regular"
  },
  {
    id: "609",
    type: "Chocolate"
  },
  {
    id: "788",
    type: "Blueberry"
  },
  {
    id: "809",
    type: "Devil's Food"
  }
]);

const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

const searchInList = () => {
  let _results = [];
  let toSearch = 609;

  for (var i = 0; i < batter.length; i++) {
    for (key in batter[i]) {
      if (batter[i][key].indexOf(toSearch) != -1) {
        _results.push(batter[i]);
      }
    }
  }
};

setResults(_results);

useEffect(() => {
  searchInList();
}, [batter]);
```

You can read more about this here: [JS search in object values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517089/js-search-in-object-values)

Comment: how could this be implemented in reactjs?