# How to get json data from a api where there are the same names as values

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, rest

i want to make a system that searches for data in json. so i have the json on an rest api. the api looks like this

```
[
    {
    "info": "cute but big animal",
    "type": "pig",
    "name": "patty"
    },
    {
    "info": "Barks all the time",
    "type": "dog",
    "name": "parker"
    },
    {
    "info": "Makes delicious eggs",
    "type": "chicken",
    "name": "chicky"
    }
]
```

there are alot of values with  the same name.

i googled alot to find some awnsers but they all say i need to number.
`data.value[1]`

i want to be able to search for patty and get the info & type
just get the json data

Javascript or nodeJS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS search in object values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517089/js-search-in-object-values)

Comment: What is the result you expect to get when you search for `patty` ?

Comment: @AdilBimzagh i want this to reply:     {
    "info": "cute but big animal",
    "type": "pig",
    "name": "patty"
    },

Comment: @HereticMonkey I go check

Answer (score 0):

If you know both the key and the value, it seems this is the simplest way:

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [
    {
    "info": "cute but big animal",
    "type": "pig",
    "name": "patty"
    },
    {
    "info": "Barks all the time",
    "type": "dog",
    "name": "parker"
    },
    {
    "info": "Makes delicious eggs",
    "type": "chicken",
    "name": "chicky"
    }
];

const key = 'name';
const value = 'patty';
const object = arrayOfObjects.find(obj => obj[key] === value);

console.log(object);
```

If you do not know the key, this is a possible way:

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [
    {
    "info": "cute but big animal",
    "type": "pig",
    "name": "patty"
    },
    {
    "info": "Barks all the time",
    "type": "dog",
    "name": "parker"
    },
    {
    "info": "Makes delicious eggs",
    "type": "chicken",
    "name": "chicky"
    }
];

const value = 'patty';
const object = arrayOfObjects.find(
  obj => Object.values(obj).some(val => val === value)
);

console.log(object);
```