# React filter array of object by any field

Tags: reactjs, filtering

Suppose I have an array of objects that have

name:
id:
school:
address:

I know how to filter by one category, such as

```
data.filter(data => data[name].includes("Lake"))
```

to get all the objects whose name includes the word Lake.

But is there a way to filter the data to get all object where any of the fields includes the word?

```
data.filter(data => data.includes("Lake"))
```

doesn't work, I already tried.

Thank you!

Comment: You might find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8517170/5179403) useful to your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const arr = [
  { id: 1, name: "name_1", school: "school_1", address: "address_1" },
  { id: 2, name: "lake", school: "school_2", address: "address_2" },
  { id: 3, name: "name_3", school: "lake", address: "address_3" },
  { id: 4, name: "name_4", school: "school_4", address: "lake" }
];

const anyKeyFilter = item => obj => Object.values(obj).includes(item);

const filteredArr = arr.filter(anyKeyFilter("lake"));

console.log(filteredArr);
```

You may use `trim()` and `.toLowerCase()` if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, name: "name_1", school: "school_1", address: "address_1" },
  { id: 2, name: "lake", school: "school_2", address: "address_2" },
  { id: 3, name: "name_3", school: "lake", address: "address_3" },
  { id: 4, name: "name_4", school: "school_4", address: "lake" }
];


const filteredArr = arr?.filter((data) => Object.values(data)?.includes('lake'));

console.log(filteredArr);
```