# navigating JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288833/how-to-search-json-tree-with-jquery) dealing with getting data from JSON. I'm trying to do almost the same, but my JSON is structured differently as far as arrays/objects and I'm not sure how to parse it the same way.

My JSON is in this format and I'm trying to write a function to find certain elements based on the linked question, but without keys for the elements in the json, not sure how to target things. Or do I need to try and rework the out put of my json? (which is being created by json_encode from a modified codeigniter db query.

```
$(function() {
var json = [
  {

    "answer": [

      "4555"

    ],
    "answer_string": "4555|",
    "qid": "70",
    "aid": "742"
  }, 
 {

    "answer": [

      "monkeys",
      "badgers",
      "monkeybadgers"

    ],
    "answer_string": "monkeys|badgers|monkeybadgers|",
    "qid": "71",
    "aid": "742"
  }
];
    $.each(json[], function(i, v) {
        if (v.qid= "70") {
            alert(v.answer[0]);
            return;
        }
    });
});​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cutcopypaste/jQmyf/)

I need to find answer[0] where qid matches a certain number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript is messed up. See updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jQmyf/2/

Specifically:  `if (v.qid= "70") {` that should be `v.qid==`

and `$.each(json[]` should just be `$.each(json`

Comment: thanks! actually did have == in the code. The reason it wasn't working in my code turns out it was because of a different problem :p

Answer (score 0):

You should give each only the name of the array:

```
$.each(ja, function(i, v) {
```

Use comparison instead of assignment inside if:

```
if (v.qid== "70") {

$(function() {
    var ja= [
      {
        "answer": [

          "4555"
        ],
        "answer_string": "4555|",
        "qid": "70",
        "aid": "742"
      }
    ];
    $.each(ja, function(i, v) {
        if (v.qid== "70") {
            alert(v.answer[0]);
            return;
        }
    });
});​
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jQmyf/9/):