# how to search in json using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have JSON data in a local file, and I have success to load using jQuery. Now I need to **search pId = "foo1"** only.

**JSON**

```
{
 "1":{
      "id": "one",
      "pId": "foo1",
      "cId": "bar1"
     },
 "2":{
      "id": "two",
      "pId": "foo2",
      "cId": "bar2"
     },
 "3":{
      "id": "three",
      "pId": "foo3",
      "cId": "bar3"
     }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
id = "1"; // Or whatever
var entry = objJsonResp[id];

console.log(entry);
```

But it shows id, `pId` and `cId` values and I only need the `pId` value, not other.

So what is the best way to get the value of `pId`

Comment: Check this please; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288833/how-to-search-json-tree-with-jquery

Comment: `console.log(entry.pId);` :)

Comment: Try logging `entry['pId']` or `entry.pId`

Comment: Please show what you have tried. This isn't a code writing service

Comment: No problema Anuj, I am glad to help you :)

Comment: also thanks @prashkr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `objJsonResp[id]` returns the whole first object.

Try using:

```
console.log(entry.pId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obj = JSON.parse("{\"1\":{\"id\": \"one\",\"pId\": \"foo1\",\"cId\": "bar1"},"2":{"id": "two","pId": "foo2","cId": "bar2"},"3":{"id": "three","pId": "foo3","cId": "bar3"}}");
// These \ are called escape chars, they say javascript that " is part of string.
```

After this you've got object of your JSON, so you have one parent object [obj] and 3 children objects ["1","2","3"] with properties of id,pId,cId. To get property of child you want to do it like parent[child_name][property_name] like this:

```
pid1 = obj["1"]["pId"];  // returns foo1
pid2 = obj["2]["pId"]; //return foo2
```

But what you asked for is JSON.parse() function, which gives you object representing your JSON

Answer (score 0):

So i have solved by help @Hackerman and @prashkr

Both comments are right.

So final solution to get only value of **pId** as asked by me is to target it like this that are provide in comments above.

```
console.log(entry.pId);
console.log(entry['pId']);
```

Comment: This is basic Javascript syntax for working with objects. It hardly deserves an answer.

Answer (score -3):

Obviously, *the server,* with whom you are communicating, is the (only) one who can return the appropriate set of results to you.   Therefore, your communication with the server must *(somehow)* include that search criteria, so that the server’s reply will only include the records of interest.   This will require additional programming on your part, on both the client and the server sides . . .