# How to recursively search specific child objects using jQuery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I know I will need to do some type of recursion, but I'm not very experienced with the syntax of js and frameworks.  I need to turn the following code into something that will search not just the Children of allNodes, but allNodes.Children[0].Children[0], allNodes.Children[1].Children[0], etc. and return the foundNode.

```
function findNodeById(id) {

        var foundNode;

        if (id === 0) {        
            foundNode = allNodes[0];
        } else {
            $.each(allNodes[0].Children, function(index, subNode) {
                if (subNode.Id === id) {
                    foundNode = subNode;
                    return false;
                }
            });
        };

        return foundNode;
    }
```

Here's what the data looks like if that helps: https://gist.github.com/matt-thorp333/09415cb90f8568f145b8b8526fc9ceb0

Comment: possible duplicate of How to search JSON tree with jQuery -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288833/how-to-search-json-tree-with-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search JSON tree with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288833/how-to-search-json-tree-with-jquery)

Comment: Not a duplicate - this works for objects that are children of the first array element only, as does my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the array as an argument so you can recursively call the function passing in Children array(s)

```js
function findNode(id, arr) {
  var foundNode = false;
  $.each(arr, function(_, item) {
    if (item.Id === id) {
      foundNode = item;
      return false;
    } else if (item.Children && item.Children.length) {
      foundNode = findNode(id, item.Children);
      return !foundNode;
    }
  });
  return foundNode;
}



$.getJSON('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/matt-thorp333/09415cb90f8568f145b8b8526fc9ceb0/raw/fa6404a2f213a4e695826bf4483cb0e2f6859c77/gistfile1.txt', function(data) {
  console.log('Found 0:', !!findNode(0, data)); // should be true
  console.log('Found 2:', !!findNode(2, data)); // should be true
  console.log('Found 3:', !!findNode(3, data));  // should be true
  console.log('Found 19:', !!findNode(19, data)); // should be false
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you were to modify the gist with deeper nested Children would see it will find them also

Comment: Yes it does, and that is what I needed vs. the suggested duplicate.  Thanks!