# Selector on a variable content with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this code :

```
jQuery('#btSave').click(function (event) {
    var jqxhr = $.post("Controller/Action", {
        lastName: $("#LastName").val()      
    },
    function (data) {
        //here
    })
});
```

I'd like to know if in the "data" variable the id "Mydiv" exist

How can I don this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean jQuery data (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) or a `data` attribute? Also, what relevance does the code you posted have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `data` is a string containing HTML markup. If so, then:

```
var tree = $(data);
if (tree.find("#Mydiv")[0]) {
    // An element with the `id` "Mydiv" exists in the tree
}
```

You don't have to use a variable, you could just do this:

```
if ($(data).find("#Mydiv")[0]) {
    // An element with the `id` "Mydiv" exists in the tree
}
```

...but I just assume you're probably going to want to do something else with `tree` afterward, so we want to avoid parsing it more than once.

**Note**: If the "Mydiv" element may be at the *top level* of the HTML in `data`, you'll want to wrap that structure in a parent element for the above to work (there are other ways, but they're more complicated). So if that may be the case, use `$("<div>" + data + "</div>")` rather than just `$(data)`. This is because `find` searches descendant elements, so if the HTML were "hi", it wouldn't find it as it's not a descendant (it's the element itself).

**Update**: Here's a [live example](http://jsbin.com/uqahe5)

Comment: J.Crowder the look not working. In fact, if "Mydiv" id is present in data, the UI behavior change (show/hide other div)

Comment: @Kris-I: Works for me. Just added a live example. Perhaps if you compare what's different, it'll help you figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can i either use RegEx or make use of String Manipulation function like IndexOf...

or

try search() String method.

```
 var isFound = data.search(new RegExp(/Mydiv/i));
```

if you are using jQery than here is alredy given answer

[jQuery .search() to any string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854493/jquery-search-to-any-string)

[Find text string using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery)

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions is fraught with peril. Not recommended. Using `String#indexOf` means any occurrence of "Mydiv" would match, even if not an `id`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do if i understood correctly.

```
if($("#Mydiv",data).length)
{
    //Mydiv exists
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can pass a string as the context parameter. Pretty sure `data` is a string in this case.

Answer (score 0):

To the extent of my understanding...

if you are trying to find div with id 'myDiv' in data...
you can do this..

```
function (data) {
        if($("#Mydiv",data)) {
            // this should do
        } 
    })
```

Be little more clear in explaining what you want....

Answer (score 0):

```
var result="limitless isa web ...";
if(result.search('limitless')>=0) // or another text Example: web
 {
   alert("ok");
 }
```