# twitter boostrap collapsible divs search

Tags: dom, twitter-bootstrap

I've the same as this http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/collapse.php and I need to create a search functionality, in order to find the searched word inside each accordion-group: inside the heading and inside the body, and highlight the matched words.

Is there a way to do it? Any idea? 
Thanks

Comment: I think that the collapse plugin doesn't have any part in your search. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1854524/1478467 for example