# jQuery - hide elements after specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to hide some elements after a specific text / the last word of the first div

```
<div class="top">here is some text</div>
<table class="middle">
...
</table>
<div class="bottom">...</div>
```

hide table(middle) and the div(bottom) depending on the word "text" from the first div

Comment: Do you think your question is more clear...??

Comment: *... and the div depending on "text"*. What `div` do you mean?

Comment: hope this helps you ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854493/jquery-search-to-any-string

Comment: If there is "text" there should table , Right ?

Comment: @PrasathK it is more clear now...

Comment: @ShibinRagh yes but the text can change so i need a unique word to say after this word "text" hide all after the first div i will try the search form dreamweiver

Comment: on what value of the `text` you want to hide/show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

http://jsfiddle.net/EnQym/1/

```
txtWord = $('.top').text().split('text')[1]
if(txtWord){
alert("div show");
}else{

alert("div hide");
}
```

Comment: what is the [1] standing for?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last word using: `$('.top').text().split(' ').pop()`, and then add some simple logic to `show/hide` the other elements:

```
var lastWord = $('.top').text().split(' ').pop();
$('.middle, .bottom').toggle(lastWord == 'text');
```

Answer (score 0):

Example if in your .top div text is hide or show the function must be:

```
var txt = $('.top').text();

if(txt=='hide')
{
   $('.middle').hide();
   $('.bottom').hide();
}
else if(txt=='show')
{
   $('.middle').show();
   $('.bottom').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check the text of the first div and show the relative div

```
    if($(".top").html() == "what you want")
    {
        $(".middle").show();
        $(".bottom").hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".bottom").show();
        $(".middle").hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastWord = function (o) {
    return ("" + o).replace(/[\s-]+$/, '').split(/[\s-]/).pop();
};

if (lastWord($('.top').html()) === "mykeyword") {
    $('.middle,.bottom').hide();
} else $('.middle,.bottom').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

lets have a method you call

```
hideOrShow(){
if(document.getElementsByClassName('top')[0].innerHtml=="the text you want"){
document.getElementsByClassName('middle')[0].style.display='none';
document.getElementsByClassName('bottom')[0].style.display='none';
}else{
document.getElementsByClassName('middle')[0].style.display='block';
document.getElementsByClassName('bottom')[0].style.display='block';
}
}
```