# Perform a function per occurrence in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery, how can I perform an alert each time a video tag occurs **in a string**. Could I base something upon the each function? Let's say the string is called "getTheCurrentResults".

```
$(getTheCurrentResults["video"]).each(function ()
{
alert ("hello");
});
```

Comment: your question is very unclear.

Comment: Please give also the "getTheCurrentResults["video"]", what is it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854493/jquery-search-to-any-string

Comment: if you want to search a substring inside a string then you have to use `Regular expression`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what type `getTheCurrentResults` is , but if it's a HTML , use roasted solution.

If it's not and you have a string and you want to perform an operation on each item  :

`$.each('27426472247'.match(/7/g),function (i,n){alert(n)})`

This  , for example , will trigger a function on each '7'.

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward What if you string contains some text with word video in it (where video doesn't represent a tag) ?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question:

```
$('<div />').html($.trim(getTheCurrentResults)).find('video').each(function ()
{
   alert ("hello");
});
```

You wrap string inside a jquery object and then use transversal method on the jq object.

Comment: @RoyiNamir not true if <video> tag is not embeded as find() search for descendants. So if video is not a descendant, nothing is returns

Comment: I dont understand. he said it is html . the video element is there so whats the problem finding it under the body element ?

Comment: even if it's an element string `jQuery(theString)` will do just fine.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Ok, you mean not using find maybe. I'm talking about case like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vPJFC/  `var getTheCurrentResults = '<video></video>';` Or, please illustrate what you mean, i don't get it

Comment: find search from childen and benieth. you should add `addBack` which is the new andSelf() http://jsbin.com/isexar/2/edit

Comment: @RoyiNamir ya using addBack() is surely better/more readable here, thx for your feedback, i appreciate

Comment: Just checked but addBack() cannot works here as it would always returns the self element even it is not a video tag: http://jsfiddle.net/qx6qC/

Comment: yeah. this can not hold all scenarious. thats why it should be a valid html and to search it under the body element.